# Java - Reusable button action handler concepts question

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, extend, jcomponent

First off - sorry for the wall of code but it's not too horrendous, just a framework for what I'm trying to explain.  It runs without errors.

*The goal*

I'm making a reuseable button class for my GUI and each button object needs to have a different handler when it's clicked.  I want to to assign a `ClickHandler` object to each new button.  Then, the button would call `init()` on the handler, and be on its way.  Unfortunately, there's a typing problem, since each handler class would have a different name.

*Current progress*

Right now, the handler is typed as `HandlerA`, but I'd like to have it handle any name, like "SettingsHandler" or "GoToTheWahWah" etc.

I've tried messing about with generic types, but since I'm new to this, and from a webdev background, there seems to be a conceptual hurdle I keep knocking over.  Is this the right way to approach the problem?

*The code*

`ReuseableButton.java` is a reuseable class, the only thing that changes is the action when it's clicked:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ReuseableButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  // I want a generic type here, not just HandlerA!
  private HandlerA ClickHandler;

  // Assemble generic button
  public ReuseableButton(Container c, String s) {
    super(s);
    addActionListener(this);
    c.add(this);
  }

  // Once again, generic type, not just HandlerA!
  public void SetClickHandler(HandlerA ch) {
    ClickHandler = ch;
  }

  // Call init() from whatever class has been defined as click handler.
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ClickHandler.init();
  }
}
```

`Controller.java` fires the frame and assembles buttons as needed (right now, only one button).

```
package gui;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Controller extends JFrame {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


  public Controller() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Handler Test GUI");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        

    Container pane = frame.getContentPane();   
    pane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    ReuseableButton b = new ReuseableButton(pane,"Reuseable Button A");
    // THE QUESTION IS HERE: Pass a generic object?
    b.SetClickHandler(new HandlerA());

    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(200,200);    
    frame.setVisible(true);        
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Controller();
  }
}
```

`HandlerA.java` is a sample of a random handler for the button click.  Later, there could be `HandlerB`, `HandlerC`, etc.

```
package gui;

// A random handler
public class HandlerA {
  public void init() {
    System.out.println("Button clicked.");
  }
}
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: for those ..., there exists Action/AbstractAction, then to try to avoid using ActionListener, good question, +1

Comment: You really don't want your GUI classes to implement your Listener interfaces. It is much better to separate the two. Also, I don't see in the code above a good reason to extend JButton.

Comment: OK great clues thanks, I'll see if I can work with them.  Right now I'm sort of hacking together various tips from here and there, but once the concepts cement together in my head, this will make more sense. :)

Comment: @Hover - the class will also include some overrides on the paint method for custom image support, so I think extending is still necessary.  But I'll keep your comment in mind, perhaps it's still true.  I'm blundering around like a blind cat at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to work with inheritence in this case:

```
public abstract class AbstractHandler {

    public abstract void init();
}
```

Then:

```
public class ConcreteHandlerA extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // do stuff...
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
public class ReuseableButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    // I want a generic type here, not just HandlerA!
    private AbstractHandler ClickHandler;

    public Controller() {
        //...

        ReuseableButton b = new ReuseableButton(pane,"Reuseable Button A");
        AbstractHandler handlerA = new ConcreteHandlerA();
        b.SetClickHandler(handlerA);

        // ...
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for...

BTW: You can define the `AbstractHandler` as an `interface` as well, but you may want to implement some common logic here as well - shared across handlers.

Comment: Looks like interfaces and inheritance are what I'm missing.  I'm accepting your solution since you offered two ways to do it.  Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: One should always use an interface unless there is a reason not to, because using an abstract class removes flexibility (it prohibits objects from inheriting from a class unrelated to yours).

Answer (score 5):

All of you handlers should implement an interface like `Clickable` or something. That way the interface specifies the existence of the init function:

```
public interface Clickable 
{
    public void init();
}
```

Making the HandlerA definition:

```
public class HandlerA implements Clickable {
    public void init() {
       System.out.println("Button clicked.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yessir will have a go - sounds like this is the concept I need.

Answer (score 3):

You should use an interface for the handler.

```
public interface ClickHandler() {
    void init();
}

ReuseableButton b = new ReuseableButton(pane,"Reuseable Button A");
b.SetClickHandler(object which implements the ClickHandler interface);
```

This is the same concept as the normal `JButton`. There you have the `ActionListener` interface and the `actionPerformed` method in it.

P.S. If I don't understand your question, please correct me.

Comment: Thanks, even if you didn't understand, I'll still learn something :)  Will try this out thanks.